# C# WPF DataGrid Contextmenu clicked column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

I have simply Datagrid and context menu. I want to get information on what column of datagrid context menu appears. In WinWorms I found solution that MouseClick shows context menu manually and remember column

```
if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right) return;
contextMenuStrip1.Show(dataGridView1, e.Location);
_ClickedColumn = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
```

How can I get column number in wpf datagrid?

Comment: You would have to create some code which listens to the ContextMenu open event. then you need to go on this path.
ContextMenu -> PlacementTarget -> Cell -> Column.

Comment: It was to easy, in MenuItem click I had to check DataGrid.CurrentColumn. That's all

Comment: if you have the answer you should mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following to get the column index.

```
var index = dataGridName.CurrentColumn;
```

Comment: Opening a columns ContextMenu does not set it as Current column.

Answer (score 1):

I've been messing with this all afternoon and came up with a solution that seems to work.

XAML

```
       <DataGrid Name="dgCSVExample"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuOpening" Handler="DataGridColumnHeader_ContextMenuOpening"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
```

CS

```
private int _LastClickedColumn = 0;

    private void DataGridColumnHeader_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        _LastClickedColumn = ((DataGridColumnHeader)sender).TabIndex;

        Debug.WriteLine("hide clicked");
    }
```

Then in the context menu option click event I was able to access the DataTable (or it would work with a List object as well) by doing this:

```
    private void miHide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataColumn dc = _dtSampleCSV.Columns[_LastColumnClicked];
        //process data here
        Debug.WriteLine("miHide clicked");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In menuItem click or ContextMenuOpening event just check DataGrid.CurrentColumn